# Use ALSA (or other software) to bind two mics to right and left channels of a single stream

Tags: sound, alsa, microphone

I have two USB microphones. I am looking to use Linux to mix these two in a particular fashion: both mics are mono output, and I want to use software to :

1. create a new audio output device (accessible in Audacity)
2. pass the output of one mic to the right channel and one mic to the left of the new output device.

I think this is possible in Alsa, but all the things I found didn't work.
Any ideas?